# Ускорение гипотетического NetBeans при реализации на C++?

Tags: java, c++

NetBeans написан на Java и временами очень сильно тормозит

- Во сколько раз он бы быстрее работал, если бы был написан на чистом С++?
- Во сколько программы на С++ работают быстрее по статистике?

Comment: А почему бы самому не оттестировать? Вот вам для раскачки: http://hashcode.ru/questions/189730

Comment: на этот вопрос можно ответить только если вы предоставите статистику

p.s. а по сути типичный холивар

Comment: Вот такая вот плачевная статистика

http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=30784

память жрет как пылесос

раз в 5 работала бы быстрее не меньше

Comment: проблема в таких сравнениях в том что очень мало людей которые являются экспертами в языках C и Java одновременно, именно поэтому все подобные сравнения ничего не стоят. по сути Java это написаный на языке С интерпретатор кода, аналогичного ассемблерному. Если делать очень приблизительное сравнение то можно вывести такие формулы:  

**Разница во времени выполнения**: время на загрузку JVM + количество инструкций в java байт коде * время поиска команды железу по операторам байт кода java.  

**Разница в использовании памяти**: размер занимаемый JVM + потребление памяти самой программой

Comment: Интересные таблички. @dfhsgfj, а в чем основная-то плачевность?

Comment: @jmu: насколько я понимаю, со времён [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) Java уже не интерпретатор байт-кода. Код компилируется в нативный.

Comment: @jmu

Java - не интерперетатор. Java - адаптированный транслятор, в чем-то круче чем .NET, в чем-то медленее.

Разница во времени выполнения будет достаточно ощутима. И состоит в том, что основная масса операций сводится в вызову библиотечных функций. Да эти функции нативные, оптимизированные под конкретную платформу, возможно даже под расширения процессора, но это все равно вызов функции для каждого чиха; в тоже время С++ многие вещи транслирует в чистый асм. Можно ещё добавить затраты на трансляцию приложения, но это мелочи.

Comment: Расход памяти - в теории - больше, за счет помоечной (использование куч и "уборки мусора") архитектуры работы с памятью. C-же даёт в массе свой мелкоблочную работу с быстрым освобождением.

Только цена в том, что написать одно и тоже приложение на С++ займет скажем две дня, на Java - день, а на VisualStudio, ну скажем 5-7 часов. Цифры конечно очень абстрактные, но порядок наверно близок.

Comment: @Silverice, а почему Вы считаете, что на С++ писать дольше, чем на Java?

В обсуждаемых замерах код C++ 850 строк, а Java 1068 строк для той же задачки. 

IMHO время написания примерно одинаково (многие считают, что его можно просто мерять в строчках кода).

Comment: @avp

Субъективно.

1. Возможно мне попадались плохие и меделенные С++ программисты :)

2. С другой стороны, если посадить за два соседних стола С-кодера и джава-кодера, и задать написать простой графический редактор для справочника в БД (в одну-две таблицы БД)... Я не думаю, что С-программист встанет из-за стола раньше. Но возможно см П.1 ))

3. Если бы С++ был самым удобным для прикладной разработки, я думаю, что не появилось бы всего остального.

Comment: @Silverlce, я ведь говорил о времени, измеренном в количестве строк. 

Видел где-то данные, что за месяц программист может написать примерно одно и то же количество строк, независимо от языка. Вот и получается, что времени на программу из 850 строк С++ уйдет даже меньше, чем на программу из 1000 строк на Java.

А для прикладной разработки важны библиотеки, которых для Java наработано больше. 

Почему? 

Видимо *приемлемо* писать на Java способен много *больший* процент людей, чем на Си/С++ (по крайней мере это ожидалось). Вот и получилось, что для них были наработаны удобные инструменты.

Comment: Как по мне - некорректно сравнивать строки. Ну, вы же не будете сравнивать строки на C++, Visual Basic, PHP или ассемблере (хотя это конечно не корректно его сюда писать, ну замнем)? Затраты на обдумывание, что писать на первом (и тем более последнем) существенно выше. Да быстродействие конечных програм тоже выше, но и вероятность ошибки и цена ошибки программиста - выше.

Так что чюдес не бывает.

Comment: @SilverIce, Вы говорите, что некорректно сравнивать строки. Думаю, Вы имеете в виду, что одна строка языка-1 выполняет существенно больше "полезной работы", чем строка языка-2. IMHO это очевидно и другого я не утверждал.

По поводу количества строк в месяц (чтобы не выглядеть голословным я нашел одну ссылку)  можете посмотреть в статье Остераута о [скриптовых языках](http://www.osp.ru/os/1998/03/179470/).

Answer (score 2):

Закрыли уже, а я тут покушать принес: [The Computer Language Benchmarks Game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/), - 
на мой взгляд, самый адекватный бенчмарк *языков*.

Может кто из местных мастеров осмелится обогнать С/С++?

Comment: Super!!!

Много, **а главное с исходниками**.

Comment: Компиляцией на ассемблер с ручным допиливанием?

Comment: Кроме абстрактной производительности языка имеет ещё значение производительность стандартных библиотек. :-P

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/05/on-managed-code-performance-again.html

(Покормил.)

Comment: @Dith: под "обогнать" вы имеете в виду аналогичный код? Я смогу обогнать, пара пустяков, этот вопрос мы уже обсуждали, когда говорили о производительности std::map. Или под "обогнать" вы имеете в виду "на некотором коде, который заточен под C++"?

Comment: @alexlz если это не противоречит правилам  
@VladD там подходящие правила, ставящие языки в равные условия  
@VladD обогнать, значит встать выше в таблице (сводной, или хотя бы по бенчмаркам)  
ждем сверхбыстрых и красивых решений на C#, которые поднимут его на должное место в этом замечательном рейтинге ;)

Comment: @VladD, я думаю @Dith просто перевел на русский призыв из текста по ссылке. 

А речь идет о десятке конкретных задач-бенчмарков. Напрмер для некой (понятия не имею, что это такое) *fasta* gcc 2.41 sec, а Java 4.92

Comment: @avp fasta - в этом бенчмарке предлагается реализовать алгоритм генерации цепочек ДНК в формате FASTA http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format

Comment: @Dith, спасибо. Правда, спасибо за набор бенчмарков. Там много есть чего почитать, думаю займусь на досуге.

Кстати, не всюду C/C++ на первом месте

    fannkuch-redux  ADA 2005
    regex-dna       JavaScript V8
    mandelbrot      Fortran Intel

Вот так.

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, но мысль такая. Суть не в самой Jave, а конкретно в библиотеке Swing, которая очень медлительна(как мне из опыта показалось). Возможно сейчас бред снес, но все же.

Comment: @alex91: ну, аналога программ со Swing'ом на C++ вообще нет: у C++ нет встроенной оконной библиотеки.

Comment: Ну и Java сама по себе не метеор, конечно)